# How to polyfill Shopify Hydrogen (Remix) with node modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, remix.run, esbuild, shopify-hydrogen

I am trying to use ReSVG-JS with Shopify Hydrogen but am encountering several issues.
At first I was building my project with `remix dev` and all was fine, however, after further integrating Shopify Hydrogen into my project I switched my `run dev` script to `npm run build:css && concurrently -g -r npm:dev:css \"shopify hydrogen dev\"`, basically building with Shopify Hydrogen now.

This is when things went sideways. I received the first error that `process` was not defined. After some research I was able to fix this by patching into the ESBuild config of Remix with [remix-esbuild-override](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remix-esbuild-override) and by [polyfilling (with this package)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-plugin-polyfill-node) `process`. Except that this was not enough and I needed to also manually patch the polyfilling package to add `process.arch` and `process.platform` in order for ReSVG to be happy.

```js
withEsbuildOverride((option, {isServer, isDev}) => {
  if (!isServer) return option;

  option.plugins = [
    ...(option.plugins ?? []),
    polyfillNode({
      globals: {
        process: true,
        buffer: true,
      },
    }),
  ];

  return option;
});
```

After that I encountered another error to do with `fs` and that there was no `existsSync`. I was able to fix this by importing into the file that imports ReSVG `installGlobals` from `@remix-run/node` and calling `installGlobals()`.

```js
import {installGlobals} from '@remix-run/node';
installGlobals();
import {Resvg} from '@resvg/resvg-js';
```

Now I was thrown into another error:

```js
TypeError: globalThis.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
    at checkTypeSupport (path\to\project\node_modules\rollup-plugin-node-polyfills\polyfills\http-lib\capability.js:20:11)
    at node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/capability.js (path\to\project\node_modules\rollup-plugin-node-polyfills\polyfills\http-lib\capability.js:39:45)
    at path\to\project\dist\worker\index.js:14:59
    at node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/request.js (path\to\project\node_modules\rollup-plugin-node-polyfills\polyfills\http-lib\request.js:1:1)
```

I tried using the polyfill package I was using and multiple others that integrate with ESBuild but sadly failed to do so.

I am completely at loss and was hoping to find someone who could help out maybe even with a completely different solution, since mine is basically beating it until it works...

Thanks!